# How to search in multiple columns using the like operator in slick?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I want to get all users from the database that have the word `foo` either in their username or in their email address. How is this written in Slick 3.x?

```
select * from users where username like '%foo%' or email like '%foo%';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose `query` is the search string: this does work:

```
Users.filter(e => (e.username like s"%$query%") || (e.email like s"%$query%")).result
```

Brackets are necessary between the `||` operator.

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined a user table, then using the tablequery object of user, you can do it by doing the following:

```
// select * from users where username like '%foo%' or email like '%foo%';
users.filter(e => e.username like '%foo%' || e.email like '%foo%').result
```

And if you run the above DBIOAction, then you will get the expected result.

http://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.1/queries.html#sorting-and-filtering

Comment: Does this compile for you? I used (and already tried before) `Users.filter(e => e.username like "%foo%" || e.email like "%foo%").result` but this does not compile as well.

Comment: You might be missing `import slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api._`, check this one
https://medium.com/@kennajenifer1234/scala-tutorial-create-crud-with-slick-and-mysql-1b0a5092899f